# How to use groupby to get arbitrary time interval data with startTime and endTime in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "DataPoint" (
"id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"startTime"  INTEGER,
"endTime"  INTEGER,
"value"  INTEGER
);
```

With these data:

```
INSERT INTO DataPoint (startTime,endTime,value) VALUES 
(1490976000000,1490997600000,1), --2017/04/01 00:00:00 ,2017/04/01 06:00:00
(1491008400000,1491030000000,2), --2017/04/01 09:00:00 ,2017/04/01 15:00:00
(1491044400000,1491051600000,3), --2017/04/01 19:00:00 ,2017/04/01 21:00:00
(1491058800000,1491069600000,4), --2017/04/01 23:00:00 ,2017/04/02 02:00:00
(1491102000000,1491120000000,5), --2017/04/02 11:00:00 ,2017/04/02 16:00:00
(1491220800000,1491222600000,6), --2017/04/03 20:00:00 ,2017/04/03 20:30:00
(1491309000000,1491316200000,7); --2017/04/04 20:30:00 ,2017/04/04 22:30:00
```

Now I want to query the sum value per day, so I tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(value) 
FROM   DataPoint 
GROUP BY (endTime-startTime)/(24*60*60*1000)
```

But it is wrong. I have no idea how to write the correct SQL query statement.

The expected result is like :

```
date       |sumValueInDay
-----------|------
2017/04/01 |6
2017/04/02 |11
2017/04/03 |6
2017/04/04 |7
```

In addition, the time interval can be arbitrary, for example, maybe I want to query the sum value per 40 minutes.

Comment: Why `(endTime-startTime)/(24*60*60*1000)`? Why not `(endTime)/(24*60*60*1000)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you [convert](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) your unix time to SQLite datetime variable, and then group by it. To convert to datetime you would use:

```
select datetime(startTime/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as startDatetime
     , datetime(endTime/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as endDatetime
     , value
FROM DataPoint;
```

Your mistake is that you use the interval `(endTime-startTime)` for grouping. You should decide which date to use (endTime or startTime) for grouping.

E.g. to group by days use:

```
select date(startTime/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as startDatetime
     , Sum(value)
FROM DataPoint
GROUP BY date(startTime/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```